# How to make a Ballerina function observable?

Tags: ballerina, observability

In Ballerina, the main, resource, and remote functions come inherently equipped with observability to enable metrics and tracing monitoring. However, I wish to extend this observability to some of the other functions within my Ballerina application.
Does Ballerina provide a way to make functions selectively observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can make any Ballerina function observable by adding the `@observe:Observable` annotation to the required functions as follows.

```php
import ballerina/observe;

@observe:Observable
function yourFunctionName() {
    // Your function logic here
}
```